# Large scale parallel 1D convolution

Tags: c++, opencl, fft, convolution, arrayfire

I'm using ArrayFire (OpenCL, not cuda) right now and I was wondering if there's any way to perform several parallel 1D convolutions (to calculate moving avg) of a really large (50M+ 32bit float) vector. I've saw some examples but with the recent open source release some of the older functionalities don't work. The window size is actually large (1k-10k). Would the FFT method (product of convolutions) be faster than the direct convolution?

Comment: Is this just a straight average over a window (i.e. all coefficients equal) ? If so then there are much more efficient methods than convolution (either direct or frequency domain) for performing a moving average. If the coefficients are not equal, i.e. if it's actually a proper filter kernel, then frequency domain convolution is usually more efficient when the filter size is of the order of 100 or greater.

Comment: Yes. Something like convolve(signal, ones(w) / w) being w the size of the window. Would you mind sharing a bit more about those methods?

Comment: Sure - it's very simple - just maintain a running sum for the window, then each time you advance the window one point you add one new data point and subtract the oldest point. So for each output value you are only doing one addition and one subtraction (and optionally dividing by the window size). This is O(n) rather than O(n^2) for direct convolution or O(n * log n) for FFT convolution.

Comment: But with the "prefix sum" approach I cannot run it in paralell since for computing the ith value i need the (i-1)th and the sample signal is really big to do that-. I'll try it but I think it would take for ever.

Comment: Well you could divide your data set into chunks and run one chunk per thread. So long as each chunk is much larger than the window size then you should still see a big improvement.

Comment: We have an issue on our github page talking about this. https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/347

    You can use the work around provided in this comment: https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/347#issuecomment-70212941

Comment: From algorithmic POV, fft method should be faster. From implementation POV - it depends.

Comment: I cant see why you say this. Pls explain